# RegEx help with password requirements

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, regex

I need regex for the following:

a string that has Min of 8 characters, including at least 2 Capital letters and 1 Number.

please help
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This article](http://www.zorched.net/2009/05/08/password-strength-validation-with-regular-expressions/) could help you build one:

```
(?=.{8,})(?=(?:.*[A-Z]){2})(?=.*[0-9])
```

Comment: If you use [A-Z], then you should use [0-9] for simmetry. In the first you are excluding for example àèéìòù plus all the non-ascii letters (japanese, arabic...), in the second you are including non-ascii digits (for example ০, BENGALI DIGIT ZERO)

Comment: @xanatos, good point, I've updated my answer to reflect this suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

This might do the trick for your specific case:

```
^(?=.{8})(?=.*[A-Z].*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).*$
```